# How to iterate over a range of a Backbone collection?

Tags: backbone.js

How to iterate over a range, lets say from the 3. to 10., of  a Backbone collection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By [slicing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) the array of models and using _.each on the result

```
var c=new Backbone.Collection(...);
_.each( c.models.slice(3,11), function(model) {
    console.log(model.get("id"));
});
```

[slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) is 0 based and the end index is excluded.

Comment: How could I tell my view : render this range, then render this range, whil keeping the full collection?

Answer (score 1):

As opposed to slicing, you can be a bit more direct by using the collection's at method.

```
for (var idx=3;idx<=10;++idx) {
    var model = collection.at(idx);
    ...do something...
}
```